# How to get data inside script tag and use as String inside function in C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I have code in file program.cs in web app .NET like this, so this code is basically draw canvas and return a link url that parse to base64 of that canvas,  im trying to look up for how to get data of c.toDataUrl , and I used

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlResponse);
var canvasDataUrl = doc.GetElementbyId("myLink").InnerHtml;
```

but it just can't take the value of  c.toDataUrl() out because in script tags it, just run after app.Run() called

```
app.MapGet("/", (HttpContext context) =>
{    string userAgent = context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];


    string htmlResponse = @"
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Canvas Fingerprint</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1>Canvas Fingerprint</h1>
                    <p>Fingerprint: {fingerprint}</p>
                    <p>Fingerprint: {canvasDataURL}</p>
                    <img style='width:500 ; height:500' src='{canvasDataURL}' alt='Canvas Fingerprint' />
<canvas id=""myCanvas"" width=""300"" height=""100"" style=""border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"">
<input type=""hidden"" id=""canvasDataUrl"">
Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>
<p id=""demo""></p>
<a id=""myLink"" href=""#"">Click me!</a>
<script>

var c = document.getElementById(""myCanvas"");
var ctx = c.getContext(""2d"");

    const txt = ""Canvas Fingerprint <canvas> 1.0"";

    // Set text baseline
    ctx.textBaseline = ""top"";

    // Set font
    ctx.font = ""14px 'Arial'"";
    ctx.textBaseline = ""alphabetic"";

    // Draw filled rectangle
    ctx.fillStyle = ""#f60"";
    ctx.fillRect(125, 1, 62, 20);

    // Draw text with color #069 at position (2, 15)
    ctx.fillStyle = ""#069"";
    ctx.fillText(txt, 2, 15);

    // Draw text with color rgba(102, 204, 0, 0.7) at position (4, 17)
    ctx.fillStyle = ""rgba(102, 204, 0, 0.8)"";
    ctx.fillText(txt, 4, 17);
    console.log(c.toDataURL());
    var canvasDataUrl = c.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById(""myLink"").innerHTML = canvasDataUrl;
</script>
                </html>";
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(htmlResponse);
    var canvasDataUrl = doc.GetElementbyId("myLink").InnerHtml;

    // Set the response content type to HTML


    return context.Response.WriteAsync(htmlResponse);
});
```

how to get value of c.toDataURL() after i draw canvas to use as a String in C#

Comment: You are mixing server side code with client side code. The html piece you are returning gets parsed and executed on the client/browser.